# How to bind routing events URL into HTML template in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an angular component with in which i am trying to bind a public variable based on the router URL. The public variable is assigned a value inside subscribe method, so because of this the template is not updated on initial load.

```
  pageTitle: string;
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
       if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          if(event.url ==="something" {
             this.pageTitle ="About US"
            }
         }
  })
}
```

I am binding the *pageTitle* variable in the HTML file

```
<div class="title">{{pageTitle}}</div>
```

On refreshing the page, i am able to see the pageTitle, but on initial load the value is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your pageTitle changes you should try to make it observable and handle with `async` pipe to keep it up to date

Added Stackblitz implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scdiic

try something like this

```
    this.title = this.route.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map((event: NavigationEnd) => event.url));
```

```html
<div class="title">{{pageTitle | async}}</div>
```

also for better understanding read about how change detection works in Angular
like here: https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/ for a good start

Comment: That didn't work. I implemented with little modification `this.pageTitle = this.router.events.pipe(map((event) => {
      return event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url.includes('something')
      ? 'About US' : 'Default Title';
    }));` I am always getting the output as **Default Title**.

Comment: it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scdiic, I have improved the Observable mapping but the idea remains same